# I have a python code to do some collatz sequence calculations but the nested while loop is not working

Tags: python

So i have this nested while loop in my code and it runs the while loop inside once instead of many many times.

```
seq = 0
largest = 0
seqNum = 0
start = 13
num = start
x = 0

while start < 1000000:
    while num != 1:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            num /= 2
            seq += 1
            print(str(seq) + " " + str(num))
        else:
            num = 3 * num + 1
            seq += 1
            print(str(seq) + " " + str(num))


if largest < seq:
    largest = seq
    big = start
    start += 1
    seq = 0

print(str(largest) + " " + str(big)+ " " + str(largest))
```

this is the output of the code when run:

```
1 40
2 20.0
3 10.0
4 5.0
5 16.0
6 8.0
7 4.0
8 2.0
9 1.0
9 13 9
```

Comment: What makes you think it only runs the inner loop once? How can you tell the difference between the inner loop and the outer loop?

Comment: You never change `start`, so `while start < 1000000` is an infinite loop.

Comment: Put `print("outer loop")` and `print("inner loop")` at the beginning of each loop and you'll see when each loop repeats.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.